# training loss increases while validation accuracy increases

Tags: optimization, keras

I am training a CNN for Binary classification of images (15k samples each) using keras and tensorflow.

This is my model :

```
#input layer : first conv layer
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,
                 kernel_size=(5,5),
                 input_shape=(256,256,3),
                 padding='same',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

# second conv layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,
                 kernel_size=(5,5),
                 padding='same',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# third layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128,
                 kernel_size=(5,5),
                 padding='same',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
# fourth layer : FC layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# prediction layer
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax',name='prediction',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
```

I am using Adam (set to default values given in keras documentation) as optimiser.
When I started training the model, it started behaving weirdly.

```
Epoch 14/180
191s - loss: 0.7426 - acc: 0.7976 - val_loss: 0.7306 - val_acc: 0.7739

Epoch 15/180
191s - loss: 0.7442 - acc: 0.8034 - val_loss: 0.7284 - val_acc: 0.8018

Epoch 16/180
192s - loss: 0.7439 - acc: 0.8187 - val_loss: 0.7516 - val_acc: 0.8103

Epoch 17/180
191s - loss: 0.7401 - acc: 0.8323 - val_loss: 0.7966 - val_acc: 0.7945

Epoch 18/180
192s - loss: 0.7451 - acc: 0.8392 - val_loss: 0.7601 - val_acc: 0.8328

Epoch 19/180
191s - loss: 0.7653 - acc: 0.8471 - val_loss: 0.7776 - val_acc: 0.8243

Epoch 20/180
191s - loss: 0.7514 - acc: 0.8553 - val_loss: 0.8367 - val_acc: 0.8170

Epoch 21/180
191s - loss: 0.7580 - acc: 0.8601 - val_loss: 0.8336 - val_acc: 0.8219

Epoch 22/180
192s - loss: 0.7639 - acc: 0.8676 - val_loss: 0.8226 - val_acc: 0.8438

Epoch 23/180
191s - loss: 0.7599 - acc: 0.8767 - val_loss: 0.8618 - val_acc: 0.8280

Epoch 24/180
191s - loss: 0.7632 - acc: 0.8761 - val_loss: 0.8367 - val_acc: 0.8426

Epoch 25/180
191s - loss: 0.7651 - acc: 0.8769 - val_loss: 0.8520 - val_acc: 0.8365

Epoch 26/180
191s - loss: 0.7713 - acc: 0.8815 - val_loss: 0.8770 - val_acc: 0.8316
```

and so on.....

**Loss in increasing and the accuracy is also increasing (both training and validation)**.

**As I am using a softmax classifier it is logical to get the starting loss ~0.69 (-ln(0.5)) but here the loss is higher than that.**

I am confused whether this is over-fitting or not.
Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: Did you check your predictions? you could be getting the same predictions for everything. Also this is a large network. Did you try just one Conv2D layer first and test results?

Comment: I haven't tried it. Will try that. But is this overfitting?

Comment: yes you are over fitting, this happens when your train loss is smaller than your validation loss, however you have a much bigger problem, in that your loss is increasing over time, which shouldn't happen because it is a minimization problem. Hard to tell what the problem is. You also only provide your network, but you should include your data processing, so others can see the entire methodology.

Comment: The datapreprocessing just involves subtracting the mean( a single number not mean image ) for each of the 3 channels for 0 centering the data. And no augmentations.

Comment: do you also divide by standard deviation?

Comment: I felt it is not necessary coz images are already normalized between [0,255]

Comment: You should still divide by sd so that all the features are scaled to the same range. I personally suspect it's the reason your loss is increasing and it can't hurt to try it.

Comment: This could be possible because loss function also accounts for the confidence of prediction but accuracy only accounts for correctness

Please check answer to similar questions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57645003/2851685

Answer (score 5):

For a binary classification you could try to change to this for your prediction layer:

```
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I am confused. How is this related to the results I am getting? Can you please explain?

Comment: You simply chose the wrong architecture for your use case. I can only speculate about your training values regarding your setup (since you didn´t give details about the selected loss and metrics in `model.compile()`.

Comment: model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),metrics = ['accuracy'])

Answer (score 0):

First of all use binary crossentropy for binary classiication, second you need to tune the learning rate, I think that the value of you learning rate is to big.

P.S. If you can tell us what are the images you are using it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You show the data for epoch 14 and higher. For prior epochs did your loss decrease monotonically? If it did then the behavior for these higher epochs is not that unusual particularly if you are not using an adjustable learning rate. It is not uncommon that a loss can go up but accuracy also increase. They are calculated by entirely different methods.Try using the Keras built in learning rate adjuster provided as keras.callbacks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau. This will reduce your learning rate over epochs based on what metric you choose to monitor. You can think the loss function as a valley in N space which narrows as you approach the minimum (see attached figure) If you have too large a learning rate as you approach the minimum (see arrows in figure) your loss will no longer decrease monotonically but actually start to rise.[Loss Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZKI6.jpg)